# Sort Object Collection by specific string C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am calling an employee search API provided by a third party which returns me a list of employees as a search result. This Employee class has n number of properties (for example, FirstName, LastName, Address, Mobile No and many others). I want to compare the "FirstName" property of these search results with the search text. If it matches, I want these matching results sorted at the top of the collection. So far, I have tried using IComparer and IComparable but they both are not suitable for my requirement. Sharing an example of my requirement below :

Example: I searched for "John" in API and API gave me 10 results. Out of these 10 results, only 1 had john as a first name, and the rest 9 of them have john in other properties. I want an employee with FirstName "John" as the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort your list via

```
var sorted = resultFromApi.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName == "John").ToList();
```

Your new list will have all items where `FirstName` is "John" in the beginning, and all items where `FirstName` has another value in the end.

Comment: Never knew I can use == with OrderBy. Thank you!

Comment: @NareshRavlani there is nothing "magical" about it when you inspect closer what is happening. The `==` generates a `bool` instead of a `string`, so now you are ordering on all the `true` and `false` values generated by each entry instead of by the text itself. Since only the values where the name is "John" generate `true`, they become isolated from the others who are all false. And since all of the others are false, they are not changed in order too.

Comment: @julealgon: Now it all makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried using IComparer and IComparable but they both are not suitable for my requirement.

You can definitely leverage `IComparer` for this:

```
public class BumpToFirstComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly string valueToBump;

    public BumpToFirstComparer(string valueToBump)
    {
        this.valueToBump = valueToBump;
    }

    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string? x, string? y)
    {
        if (x == this.valueToBump) return -1;
        if (y == this.valueToBump) return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Notice how we say that "every element is identical, with the exception of this special case that I want to handle: if the special case is found as the first in the comparison, we always say it should come *before* the second, and if it is found as the second, then the second always comes first.

You can then just pass this into any ascending sorting method and it should give you the results you want:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetInput()
{
    yield return "Juliano";
    yield return "SomeoneElse";
    yield return "John";
    yield return "YetAnotherPerson";
}

foreach (var ordered in GetInput().Order(new BumpToFirstComparer("John")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ordered);
}
```

This produces:

> John
>
> Juliano
>
> SomeoneElse
>
> YetAnotherPerson

`John` is now at the top, while the rest of the list remains intact.